# How do I run Firefox OS as a standalone application?

Tags: firefox, emulation, firefox-extensions

I got the [add-on for the Firefox OS simulator](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/2012/11/08/r2d2b2g-is-becoming-the-firefox-os-simulator/), and it works great! It even keeps functioning after Firefox is closed, so I can save processing power for other things.

I'd like to run it as a standalone application, so that I don't even have to open Firefox in the first place.
I've gone to the System Monitor, and it says that the process (I guessed which by CPU usage and filename) was started via `/home/james/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/vkuuxfit.default/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/resources/r2d2b2g/data/linux64/b2g/plugin-container 3386 true tab`, so I tried running that in the Terminal (after I'd closed the simulator, of course,) but it gives this:

```
james@james-OptiPlex-GX620:~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/vkuuxfit.default/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/resources/r2d2b2g/data/linux64/b2g$ ./plugin-container 3386 true tab
./plugin-container: error while loading shared libraries: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
james@james-OptiPlex-GX620:~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/vkuuxfit.default/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/resources/r2d2b2g/data/linux64/b2g$
```

What should I do? Is what I'm attempting even possible? (It should be, since the simulator kept running even after Firefox itself was closed...)

NOTE: I've tried `chmod u+sx plugin-container`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

**AWWWWWW YEEEEEEAAAAAHHHH!!!**

I figured it out! Turns out that there's a special version of it designed to be run by itself. (As soon as I posted the question, I began to do some research myself. I found what I needed.)

I've made an installation script, if anybody wants it: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/98745514/firefox-os-installer.sh
People with 64-bit computers, please open it with a text editor and follow the comment instructions.

To uninstall, type

```
sudo rm -R /opt/b2g  
sudo rm /usr/bin/b2g
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/b2g.desktop
```

You're welcome!

---

## Better Way:

At the terminal, run

```
~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/{PROFILE_NAME}/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/resources/r2d2b2g/data/linux64/b2g/b2g -profile ~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/{PROFILE_NAME}/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/resources/profile
```

...change `linux64` to `linux` if on a 32-bit machine.

I have mine set up where `~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/{PROFILE_NAME}/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/resources/r2d2b2g/data/linux64/b2g` is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/b2g`, and a simple launching script has been written at `/usr/bin/b2g`.